# Metamask alternative for native mobile applications

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development, mobile-wallet

I am trying to find out if there is a solution like Metamask for native mobile application.
I want a metamask like solution for mobile applications where there are these options

- Connect to ethereum/binance network: When trying to connect to blockchain network from app, a pop up should appear for user's consent.
- Sending a Transaction: When app is trying to send a transaction, a pop up should appear for user's consent, just like metamask provide for web dapps.

I know there is metamask mobile, but it provides an inbuilt browser where we can browse web based dapps and connect to it metamask on mobile. But this is not the solution as i want to connect by native mobile application to binance/ethereum network.

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution for this?